# specifying object will have a specific property but the rest are ambiguous with React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I created a custom hook, quite simple, used to fetch and return data.

**useFetchData**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const useFetchData = (
  URI: string
): [any[] | null, boolean, string | null] => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<any[] | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch(URI);
        setData(await res.json());
        setTimeout(() => {
          setLoading(false);
        }, 2000);
      } catch (err) {
        setErrorMessage(err.message);
      }
    };

    if (!URI) return;
    fetchData();
  }, [URI]);

  return [data, loading, errorMessage];
};
```

using TypeScript, I want to specific that the `any[]` type belonging to `data` should have at the very least a property `id: string | number` what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `{id: string | number}[]`. Any object that has the id property is assignable to this type, since they are all **subtypes** of it.